# I want to insert multiple array to XML in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got many values from html rows table and I want to submit with XML Array, but I don't know how to change to array multidimension in php array.

and this is my array

```
    Array
(
    [RSVRS_TRX_H_ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )
    [RSVRS_TRX_D_ID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )
    [PROCESS_STAT] => 
    [IMG_CODE] => Array
        (
            [0] => KTP_IMG
            [1] => KWIT_IMG
        )
    [IMG_DATA] => Array
        (
            [0] => iniktpimg
            [1] => inilkwit
        )
    [NEED_REVISION] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 0
        )
    [NOTES] => Array
        (
            [0] => ya
            [1] => tidak
        )
    [USR_CRT] => 30305
)
```

and i want to multidimensional array like this or it's just to looping?

```html
Array
(
    Array(
        [RSVRS_TRX_H_ID] => 2
        [RSVRS_TRX_D_ID] => 3
        [PROCESS_STAT] => 
        [IMG_CODE] => KTP_IMG
        [IMG_DATA] => iniktpimg
        [NEED_REVISION] => 1
        [NOTES] => ya
        [USR_CRT] => 30305
    ),
    Array(
        [RSVRS_TRX_H_ID] => 2
        [RSVRS_TRX_D_ID] => 4
        [PROCESS_STAT] => 
        [IMG_CODE] => KWIT_IMG
        [IMG_DATA] => inilkwit
        [NEED_REVISION] => 0
        [NOTES] => tidak
        [USR_CRT] => 30305
    )
)
```

Comment: this isn't something done by just one function.
You will have to create a new array, iterating the previous one, and putting keys and values accordingly

Comment: You say you "want to submit with XML Array" - what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

loop over all array get key and value of array.  loop over each value of array, assign to each key its values at numbers index of result number index come from value of array. if value is not array assign value with key to each number index of result.

```
array_walk($array, function($value, $key)use (&$result){
    if(is_array($value) && !is_null($value)){
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) { 
            $result[$k][$key]=$v;   
        }
    }else
    {
        foreach ($result as $rkey => $rvalue) { 
            $result[$rkey][$key] =$value;
        }

    }
});

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [RSVRS_TRX_H_ID] => 2 
    [RSVRS_TRX_D_ID] => 3 
    [PROCESS_STAT] => 
    [IMG_CODE] => KTP_IMG 
    [IMG_DATA] => iniktpimg 
    [NEED_REVISION] => 1 
    [NOTES] => ya 
    [USR_CRT] => 30305 ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [RSVRS_TRX_H_ID] => 2 
    [RSVRS_TRX_D_ID] => 4 
    [PROCESS_STAT] => 
    [IMG_CODE] => KWIT_IMG 
    [IMG_DATA] => inilkwit 
    [NEED_REVISION] => 0 
    [NOTES] => tidak 
    [USR_CRT] => 30305 ) )
```